# TypeError: changes.payload.docChanges is not a function in Angular 6 using AngularFire2 v5-rc9

Tags: angular, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, angularfire2

I'm getting this error in latest ("angularfire2": "^5.0.0-rc.9"). My code is the same as in [this example](https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/blob/5dcc354e21eeeb9d341d0e618212ecde1b3adc6f/docs/firestore/collections.md#example)
I can see this error occurs to other developers [on github](https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/issues/1653) too but didn't found any solution. I'm using Angular 6 and latest version of chrome.

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { AngularFirestore, AngularFirestoreCollection } from 'angularfire2/firestore';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';

export interface Shirt { name: string; price: number; }
export interface ShirtId extends Shirt { id: string; }

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  template: `
    <ul>
      <li *ngFor="let shirt of shirts | async">
        {{ shirt.name }} is {{ shirt.price }}
      </li>
    </ul>
  `
})
export class AppComponent {
  private shirtCollection: AngularFirestoreCollection<Shirt>;
  shirts: Observable<ShirtId[]>;
  constructor(private readonly afs: AngularFirestore) {
    this.shirtCollection = afs.collection<Shirt>('shirts');
    // .snapshotChanges() returns a DocumentChangeAction[], which contains
    // a lot of information about "what happened" with each change. If you want to
    // get the data and the id use the map operator.
    this.shirts = this.shirtCollection.snapshotChanges().pipe(
      map(actions => actions.map(a => {
        const data = a.payload.doc.data() as Shirt;
        const id = a.payload.doc.id;
        return { id, ...data };
      }))
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Using Ctrl+F, `docChanges` is unfindable in the page you provided. Are you sure you're using the correct function  ?

Comment: actually there is no function like this but I'm getting error for this.

Comment: Then provide the code you tried, or an [mcve]

Comment: Code is exactly same but with different collection name although i added it here and is also available in that example link i shared

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Recent releases of AngularFire require Firebase 5.0.2+, they changed `docChanges` from a property to a function. Ensure that you've upgraded `@firebase/firestore` and `@firebase/firestore-types` in your `package.json`.

Answer (score -1):

Angular 6 introduced RXJS 6 which changed the way RXJS was used. Migration link [here](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/MIGRATION.md). But Angularfire2 was not updated to RXJS yet. Wait for them to update. In the mean time you can use rxjs-compact and have backward compatibility

```
npm install rxjs-compat --save
```

Comment: I've already did that. This error is due to angularfire2 module.

Comment: I know its due to angularfire2 module, for that only we need rxjs-compact.